# Constructing numbers $x<0 \land x>1,x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: number-theory

$x<0 \land x>1,x\in\mathbb{R}$ obviously it is not possible to have a number which is smaller than 0 and greater than 1, however would it be possible to construct numbers having those identities.

Comment: You mean, similar to the way $x^2+1=0$ has no solution in $\Bbb R$, but we can work with the larger field $\Bbb C$?

Comment: exactly. this is another way mathematicians think, theoretically it should be possible, but dunno

Answer (score 4):

We extend our notion of "number" from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$ so be able to solve equations such as $x+1=0$. We extend from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Q$ in order to solve equations such as $2x=1$. We extend from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb R$ to handle llimit processes. We extend from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb C$ to solve equations such as $x^2+1=0$.

But whenever we extend our notion to gain "new" numbers, we also lose something in exchange. E.g., the principle of induction (or well-order) that can be used to prove things in $\Bbb N$ does not hold for $\Bbb Z$ any more. And further down the road, $\Bbb C$ is no longer an ordered field as $\Bbb R$ was. There are even further useful extensions where we use commutativity of multiplications (the quaternions) or even associativity (octaves).

So what would we *have* to lose if we extended $\Bbb R$ to some larger set $X$ where there exists some $x\in X$ with both $x<1$ and $1<x$?
If $x<1$ and $1<x$, then $<$ cannot be a total order any more - or even a partial order. But that means that it becomes a somewhat useless relation. For if we are about to destroy usefulness of $<$ anyway, we can just take $X=\Bbb C$ and define $1<i$ and $i<1$, say. To repeat, this does not turn $\Bbb C$ into an ordered field (i.e., a field that is not only ordered, but in fact is ordered in a way compatible with the field operations), and it doesn't even turn it into a partially ordered set. At this point, using the well-known symbol $<$ for such a relation becomes confusing at least.
Instead  of $\Bbb C$, we could also try a polynomial ring $\Bbb R[Y]$ with the convention $1<Y$ and $Y<1$ (and still no partial order).
Or simply something like $\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ (which even somehow makes sense). Or ... at any rate we essentially forget about $<$.

Comment: thank you for your great answer. :)